# How to manage parameter value from query string in hash mode

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

A URL as like

> http://somedomain.com/path/to/app?code=123#/route/of/app?foo=bar

How to manage parameter values both of code and foo in react-router ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `this.props.location.search` in your component- this will give you query parameters. Then you can split by `#` to retrieve `code=123` and the other part, that can then be split by `?` to get the `foo=bar` part.

Comment: Yes, that's a way. But I want to change or get the value by react-router 。 For example, I want to go to `http://somedomain.com/path/to/app/#/other/route/of/app` from `http://somedomain.com/path/to/app?code=123#/route/of/app?foo=bar` . And how to reach it in react-router ?

Comment: react-router is just a library for handling routing. Where do you want to do that, maybe some code will be helpful? You may add <Link> element in your component that points to some url.

Comment: `Link` can not handle real query parameters in hash mode